# Is validates_presence_of necessary if using validates_length_of?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

In an ActiveRecord model is it considered best practice/necessary to use `validates_presence_of` when also using `validates_length_of`?

For example:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_length_of   :name, :in => 5..30
end
```

To me, it seems redundant. Having a length between 5 and 30 means that the attribute is also present, yet I see this used everywhere. It also means users get two error messages regarding the same missing attribute, when really only one is needed.

Am I missing something, or are people being overly-zealous when validating data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

validates_presence_of is entirely redundant when used with validates_length_of, except in cases where you supply `:allow_nil => true` or `:allow_blank => true` to validates_length_of.

Default values for the allow_nil and allow_blank options in any validation is false. validates_presence_of only fails if the attribute is neither nil, or blank. Therefore validates_presence_of is made redundant by most of the supplied validations when neither allow_nil or allow_blank is supplied as options to the validation.

Answer (score 3):

People are being overly-zealous. You can use both, but the user would have a poor experience unless you pass `:allow_nil` to `validates_length_of`.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought. 

:allow_nil is only useful if the company name has to be between 5 and 30 characters, or can be missing. If you want the company name to be between 5 and 30 characters long you *wouldn't* want :allow_nil.